# Why List for Recyclerview returning same items in all positions?

Tags: java, android, collections, android-recyclerview

In my android app, I am using recycler view to show items.

(Note: This is not a duplicate question because I tried many answers from stackoverflow but no solution.)

**My Problem**
   The recycler view showing repeated items. A single item is repeating many times even though it occurs only single time in the source DB.

I checked for the reason and note that the List object in Adapter class returning same values in all iterations. But the Fragment that sends List object to adapter class having unique values.

But only the adapter class after receiving the List object contains duplicate items

**Solutions I tried**

- I checked Stackoverflow and added  getItemId(int position) and getItemViewType(int position) in adaptor class but no solution
- I checked the DB and also List view sending class both dont have duplicate items.

**My Code:**

*InboxHostFragment.java = This class sends List object to adaptor class of recycler view:*

```
public class HostInboxFragment extends Fragment {

 View hostinbox;
 Toolbar toolbar;
 ImageView archive, alert, search;
 TextView blank;
 Bundle args = new Bundle();

 private static final String TAG = "Listinbox_host";

 private InboxHostAdapter adapter;
 String Liveurl = "";
 RelativeLayout layout, host_inbox;
 String country_symbol;
 String userid;
 String login_status, login_status1;

 ImageButton back;

 String roomid;
 RecyclerView listView;
 String name = "ramesh";

 private int start = 1;

 private List < ListFeed > movieList = new ArrayList < > ();
 String currency1;
 // RecyclerView recyclerView;
 public HostInboxFragment() {

 }

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 }

 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
 public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  hostinbox = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_host_inbox, container, false);

  FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(getContext().getAssets(), getString(R.string.app_font));
  fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) hostinbox);

  SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
  userid = prefs.getString("userid", null);
  currency1 = prefs.getString("currenycode", null);

  toolbar = (Toolbar) hostinbox.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  archive = (ImageView) hostinbox.findViewById(R.id.archive);
  alert = (ImageView) hostinbox.findViewById(R.id.alert);
  search = (ImageView) hostinbox.findViewById(R.id.search);
  blank = (TextView) hostinbox.findViewById(R.id.blank);

  host_inbox = (RelativeLayout) hostinbox.findViewById(R.id.host_inbox);

  layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  start = 1;

  final String url = Constants.DETAIL_PAGE_URL + "payment/host_reservation_inbox?userto=" + userid + "&start=" + start + "&common_currency=" + currency1;
  //*******************************************ListView code start*****************************************************
  System.out.println("url in Inbox page===" + url);

  movieList.clear();
  JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
     //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

     // Parsing json
     // for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
     try {

      JSONArray contact = response.getJSONArray("contact");
      obj_contact = contact.optJSONObject(0);

      login_status1 = obj_contact.getString("Status");


      // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      host_inbox.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

      ListFeed movie = new ListFeed();
      for (int i = 0; i < contact.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject obj1 = contact.optJSONObject(i);


       movie.getuserby(obj1.getString("userby"));
       movie.resid(obj1.getString("reservation_id"));
       movie.setresidinbox(obj1.getString("reservation_id"));
       System.out.println("reservation iddgdsds" + obj1.getString("reservation_id"));
       movie.setuserbys(obj1.getString("userby"));
       movie.setuserto(obj1.getString("userto"));
       movie.setid(obj1.getString("room_id"));
       movie.getid1(obj1.getString("id"));
       movie.userto(obj1.getString("userto"));
       movie.isread(obj1.getString("isread"));
       movie.userbyname(obj1.getString("userbyname"));
       country_symbol = obj1.getString("currency_code");
       Currency c = Currency.getInstance(country_symbol);
       country_symbol = c.getSymbol();
       movie.setsymbol(country_symbol);


       movie.setTitle(obj1.getString("title"));
       movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj1.getString("profile_pic"));
       movie.setstatus(obj1.getString("status"));
       movie.setcheckin(obj1.getString("checkin"));
       movie.setcheckout(obj1.getString("checkout"));
       movie.setcreated(obj1.getString("created"));
       movie.guest(obj1.getString("guest"));
       movie.userbyname(obj1.getString("username"));
       movie.getprice(obj1.getString("price"));
       String msg = obj1.getString("message");
       msg = msg.replaceAll("<b>You have a new contact request from  ", "");
       msg = msg.replaceAll("</b><br><br", "");
       msg = msg.replaceAll("\\w*\\>", "");
       movie.message(msg);

       movieList.add(movie);
       System.out.println(movieList.get(i).message()); // returning unique values

       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
     }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
   @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    stopAnim();
    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
      "Check your Internet Connection",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   }
  });

 // Adding request to request queue
 AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
 movieReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

 return hostinbox;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
 Log.w(TAG, "App stopped");

 super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
 super.onDestroy();
}


public boolean isOnline(Context c) {
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c
  .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

 return ni != null && ni.isConnected();
}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

> In the above code , `System.out.println(movieList.get(i).message());` returning **unique** values without any problem.

*Inboxhostadapter.java = This is the adapter for recycleview*

```
public class InboxHostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < InboxHostAdapter.CustomViewHolder > {
 private List < ListFeed > feedItemList;
 private ListFeed listFeed = new ListFeed();
 String userid = "",
 tag,
 str_currency;
 String reservation_id,
 Liveurl,
 india2 = "0";
 ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
 String currency1;
 String status1;
 //private Activity activity;
 public Context activity;
 public InboxHostAdapter(Context activity, List < ListFeed > feedItemList, String tag) {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
  Liveurl = sharedPreferences.getString("liveurl", null);
  userid = sharedPreferences.getString("userid", null);
  currency1 = sharedPreferences.getString("currenycode", null);

  this.feedItemList = feedItemList; // returning duplicate items

  this.activity = activity;
  listFeed = new ListFeed();
  this.tag = tag;
  SharedPreferences prefs1 = activity.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MY_PREFS_LANGUAGE, MODE_PRIVATE);
  str_currency = prefs1.getString("currencysymbol", null);
  if (str_currency == null) {
   str_currency = "$";
  }
 }

 @Override
 public InboxHostAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hostinbox, parent, false);
  FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(activity.getAssets(), activity.getString(R.string.app_font_light));
  fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) view);
  return new CustomViewHolder(view);

 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(InboxHostAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

  // This block returning duplicate items

  listFeed = feedItemList.get(position); // This list feedItemList returning duplicate items

  reservation_id = listFeed.getid();
  System.out.println("reservation id after getting in inbox adapter" + reservation_id);
  System.out.println("check out after getting" + listFeed.getcheckout());
  System.out.println("message after getting in inbox adapter" + listFeed.getTitle());
  System.out.println("symbol after getting" + listFeed.getsymbol());
  System.out.println("username after getting" + listFeed.getaddress());
  System.out.println("price after getting" + listFeed.getprice());
  System.out.println("status after getting" + listFeed.getstatus());
  System.out.println("check in after getting" + listFeed.getcheckin());
  System.out.println("check out after getting" + listFeed.getcheckout());
  System.out.println("userby  after getting====" + listFeed.getuserby());
  System.out.println("message  after getting====" + listFeed.message());
  String msg;
  msg = listFeed.message();

  holder.name.setText(listFeed.userbyname());
  holder.time.setText(listFeed.getcreated());
  holder.date1.setText(listFeed.getcheckin());
  holder.date2.setText(listFeed.getcheckout());

  if (listFeed.guest().equals("1")) {
   holder.guest.setText(listFeed.guest() + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.guests));
  } else {
   holder.guest.setText(listFeed.guest() + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.guests));

  }

  if (tag.equals("Listinbox_service_host")) {
   holder.guest.setText("");
   holder.ttt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  } else {
   holder.guest.setText(listFeed.guest() + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.guests));
  }

  //  holder.status.setText(listFeed.getstatus());
  holder.title.setText(listFeed.getTitle());
  status1 = listFeed.getstatus();
  if (status1.equals("Accepted")) {
   holder.status.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.accepted_details));
  }
 } else if (status1.equals("Contact Host")) {
  holder.status.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.Contact_Host));
  holder.guestmsg.setText(listFeed.message());

 } else {
  holder.status.setText(status1);
 }

 if (currency1 == null) {
  currency1 = "$";
 }
 if (listFeed.getprice() != null && !listFeed.getprice().equals("null")) {
  DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
  money.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
  india2 = money.format(new Double(listFeed.getprice()));
  holder.currency.setText(listFeed.getsymbol() + " " + india2);
  holder.currency.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(holder.currency));

 }
 //view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));
 System.out.println("listview price" + listFeed.getprice());
 System.out.println("listview useds" + listFeed.getresidinbox());
 System.out.println("listview dffdd" + listFeed.getuserbys());
 System.out.println("listview dfffdgjf" + listFeed.getuserto());

 //holder.bucket.setTag(position);
 System.out.println("Activity name" + tag);
 holder.inbox.setTag(position);
 holder.inbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

   int position = (int) v.getTag();
   Intent search = new Intent(activity, Inbox_detailshost.class);
   search.putExtra("userid", userid);
   search.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   activity.startActivity(search);
   System.out.println("listview useds" + listFeed.getresidinbox());
   System.out.println("listview dffdd" + listFeed.getuserbys());
   System.out.println("listview dfffdgjf" + listFeed.getuserto());

  }
 });

}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
 System.out.println("list item size" + feedItemList.size());
 return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 return position;
}

class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 ImageView thumbNail;
 TextView name, time, date1, date2, currency, guest, status, title, ttt, guestmsg;
 RelativeLayout inbox;

 CustomViewHolder(View view) {
  super(view);
  if (imageLoader == null)
   imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
  this.thumbNail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
  this.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title2);
  this.time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView4);
  this.date1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
  this.date2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView22);
  this.currency = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView23);
  this.guest = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView25);
  this.ttt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView24);
  this.status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView26);
  this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView28);
  this.inbox = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.inbox);
  this.guestmsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.guestmessage);
 }
}
public class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

 private DecimalFormat df;
 private DecimalFormat dfnd;
 private boolean hasFractionalPart;

 private TextView et;

 public NumberTextWatcher(TextView et) {
  df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
  df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
  dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
  this.et = et;
  hasFractionalPart = false;
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 private static final String TAG = "NumberTextWatcher";

 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

  try {
   int inilen, endlen;
   inilen = et.getText().length();

   String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
   Number n = df.parse(v);
   int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
   if (hasFractionalPart) {
    et.setText(df.format(n));
   } else {
    et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
   }
   endlen = et.getText().length();
   int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
   if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
    et.setSelected(true);
   }
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
   // do nothing?
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   // do nothing?
  }

  et.addTextChangedListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()))) {
   hasFractionalPart = true;
  } else {
   hasFractionalPart = false;
  }
 }

}
}
```

> In the above code , **feedItemList** returning duplicate values eventhogh the movieList list from source clas Inboxfragment.java contains unique values.

Kindly please help me with this issue. I tried many answers in Stackoverflow but I can't get solutions. I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Where is the recyclerview in your code?

Comment: I don't know what all that up there is, but please see CustomAdapter class of https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView on how to setup a RecyclerView! And see the Fragment to see how its called.

Comment: @Ragesh D Antony What's the purpose of

 if (listFeed.guest().equals("1")) {
   holder.guest.setText(listFeed.guest() + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.guests));
  } else {
   holder.guest.setText(listFeed.guest() + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.guests));
  }

In true and false part you are doing same thing.

Comment: Could you show us the caller code to create the InboxHostAdapter "public InboxHostAdapter(Context activity, List < ListFeed > feedItemList, String tag)". I want to check how do you get the "feedItemList".

Comment: The issue was fixed by following the steps mentioned in the answer below by @SSALPHAX . Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code

```
  for (int i = 0; i < contact.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject obj1 = contact.optJSONObject(i);
   ListFeed movie = new ListFeed();

   movie.getuserby(obj1.getString("userby"));
   movie.resid(obj1.getString("reservation_id"));
   movie.setresidinbox(obj1.getString("reservation_id"));
   System.out.println("reservation iddgdsds" + obj1.getString("reservation_id"));
   movie.setuserbys(obj1.getString("userby"));
   movie.setuserto(obj1.getString("userto"));
   movie.setid(obj1.getString("room_id"));
   movie.getid1(obj1.getString("id"));
   movie.userto(obj1.getString("userto"));
   movie.isread(obj1.getString("isread"));
   movie.userbyname(obj1.getString("userbyname"));
   country_symbol = obj1.getString("currency_code");
   Currency c = Currency.getInstance(country_symbol);
   country_symbol = c.getSymbol();
   movie.setsymbol(country_symbol);


   movie.setTitle(obj1.getString("title"));
   movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj1.getString("profile_pic"));
   movie.setstatus(obj1.getString("status"));
   movie.setcheckin(obj1.getString("checkin"));
   movie.setcheckout(obj1.getString("checkout"));
   movie.setcreated(obj1.getString("created"));
   movie.guest(obj1.getString("guest"));
   movie.userbyname(obj1.getString("username"));
   movie.getprice(obj1.getString("price"));
   String msg = obj1.getString("message");
   msg = msg.replaceAll("<b>You have a new contact request from  ", "");
   msg = msg.replaceAll("</b><br><br", "");
   msg = msg.replaceAll("\\w*\\>", "");
   movie.message(msg);

   movieList.add(movie);
   System.out.println(movieList.get(i).message()); // returning unique value

  }
```

Declare `ListFeed movie = new ListFeed();` into the `for Loop`
And remove the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from `for Loop`.

I think this help you.

Comment: Problem resolved. I just copied your code and replaced it. More than 6 hours I tried. But you fixed me in 6 minutes .. Thanks.

Comment: Will you please explain the process that creates this issue and also how it got resolved ? @SSALPHAX

Comment: @RageshDAntony yes the model ListFeed not initialize every time and adapter change every time when for loop call thats why recyclerview get duplicate values

Comment: Thanks for you help !!!

Comment: @RageshDAntony welcome